# Write text from edit control in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In my Program,
I need set text in editbox
i have a edit box and 
I added a variable name to the text edit control which is txtShow
 how to write something in edit box in event from button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhczy8bz.aspx) is the function you need - `CEdit` inherits this from `CWnd`.

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx):

> **CEdit** inherits significant functionality from **CWnd**. To set and retrieve text from a **CEdit** object, use the **CWnd** member
>   functions `SetWindowText` and `GetWindowText`, which set or get the
>   entire contents of an edit control, even if it is a multiline control.
>   Text lines in a multiline control are separated by '\r\n' character
>   sequences. Also, if an edit control is multiline, get and set part of
>   the control's text by calling the **CEdit** member functions
>   `GetLine`, `SetSel`, `GetSel`, and `ReplaceSel`.

So if your `CEdit` memvariable is called `txtShow`, you just do this:

```
txtShow.SetWindowText(_T("Some text"));
```

As you're using MFC, you can take an easier approach and right-click on the edit box in the dialog designer and choose *Add variable*, then choose the option to associate a `CString` variable with the edit control. Then you just need to assign text to that `CString` and call `UpdateData(FALSE)` to refresh the dialog.

Comment: I need a code plz write code

Comment: Look MSDN or VC++ sample code, there are more than enough code examples.

Comment: If you are given the name of a function call along with a link to the documentation, but you still can't figure out how to write the code, you should give up programming and find a new hobby/career. Sorry, I know that's harsh, but it's time someone was honest with you, @user.